# Register multiple classes dynamically in service provider

Tags: php, laravel, provider, service-provider, laravel-6.2

I have multiple `ModuleServiceProvider` in different modules folder and i trying to register dynamically in one `RootServiceProvider`.

`ModuleServiceProvider`

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class, CategoryRepository::class);
}
```

here is my code in `rootServiceProvider`

```php
public function boot()
{
  foreach(glob(app_path().'/Azam/Modules/*/Providers/*.php') as $provider) {
     $this->app->register($provider);
  }
}
```

and the error I'm getting

> Class '/Users/.../Desktop/Developments/Codes/project/app/Azam/Modules/Categories/Providers/CategoryServiceProvider.php' not found

my file path looks good.

Answer (score 2):

The `register()` method is expecting a fully-qualified class name, not a file path.

You could use a standard location and naming strategy for your service providers, in order to loop them based on the module name:

```php
/** @var \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem $filesystem */
$filesystem = $this->app->make('files');

foreach ($files->directories(app_path('Azam/Modules')) as $directory) {
    $directoryName = last(explode('/', $directory));


    $this->app->register("App\\Azam\\Modules\\{$directoryName}\\{$directoryName}ServiceProvider");
}
```

Or, if you want to glob the entire module and find any service providers with any particular name, you'll have to find the classes within each file and determine if any extend the `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider` class, or have a particular name suffix (e.g. `ServiceProvider`).

Comment: i copy your code and pasted. getting this error now Class 'App\Azam\Modules\{/Users/saifulazam/Desktop/Developments/Codes/package/app/Azam/Modules/Categories}\Providers\{/Users/saifulazam/Desktop/Developments/Codes/package/app/Azam/Modules/Categories}ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Please see the edited answer. I forgot a step when writing the code sample from memory. Keep this in mind when you request help from StackOverflow or outside places -- the code is not always guaranteed to be perfect for your situation. Debugging it yourself will be important!

Comment: now this  Class 'App\Azam\Modules\{Categories}\Providers\{Categories}ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: You'll figure it out. :)